# React JS, how pass data to component from MDX file?

Tags: reactjs, mdx, blogs

I have an mdx file with some data to create a blog post.
The mdx file structure is the following

```
---
title: MDX is Magical2!
path: /mdx2
date: 2019-08-25
---

import Diary from "../../components/Diary";

export const days = [
  {
    daytitle: "Day1",
    description: "desc 1",
    cover: "./img.jpg"
  },
  {
    daytitle: "Day2",
    description: "desc 2",
    cover: "./img.jpg"
  },
];

<Diary data={days} />
```

and my component Diary is the following:

```
import React from 'react';

const Diary = ({ data }) => (
  <div >
    <h2 
    >
    
        {data.days.daytitle}
    </h2>    

  </div>
  
);

export default Diary;
```

That give me the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'days')

Can someone help me to fix this?

Thanks

Another version I tried is

```
import React from 'react';

const Diary = ({ daytitle }) => (
  <div >
    <h2 
    >
    
        {daytitle}
    </h2>    

  </div>
  
);

export default Diary;
```

This doesn't display nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are close! `days` is an array of object but you are not treating it that way in the code. Change your `Diary` component to something like this so that it loops through `days` and displays an `h2` for each day in the array:

```
import React from 'react';

const Diary = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    {data.map(day => {
        return (
            <h2>
                {day.daytitle}
            </h2>  
        )
    })
  </div>
  
);

export default Diary;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you're passing is an array (of days).

And you're trying to read the `days` property of that array. Arrays don't have a `days` property.

If you want a component which takes in an array and then iterates through it, you have to use `.map`:

```
const Diary = ({ days }) => (
  <>
    {days.map(({ daytitle }, key) => (
      <div key={key}>
        <h2>{daytitle}</h2>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

---

Or you could have a DiaryEntry responsible for rendering a single day and handle the looping/mapping outside:

```
const DiaryEntry = ({ day }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{day.daytitle}</h2>
  </div>
)
```

and use it as:

```
import DiaryEntry from '../../components/DiaryEntry'

const Diary = ({ days }) => (
  <>
    {days.map((day, key) => (
      <DiaryEntry {...{ day, key }} />
    ))}
  </>
)
```

*Note*: when mapping, you need a `key`. It doesn't have to be the element's `index` in the array. React uses this to identify the element in the array. It has to be a unique identifier (`uuid`, the actual date, ...).